# How can I filter my records based on this specific criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have the following `T-SQL` query:

```
SELECT a.ResaID,
       b.CheckInDate, 
       c.ProfileID  

FROM RSD a
LEFT JOIN GSS b on b.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN RS c on c.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN Profile d on d.ProfileID = c.ProfileID
```

An extract of the output of the above query is shown below:

```
  ResaID      CheckInDate    ProfileID

  100         2018-03-10      450
  101         2018-03-15      658
  102         2018-03-15      658
  103         2018-03-24      700
  115         2018-06-11      700
  127         2018-07-09      851
```

I need to filter this output so that it gives me only those records where the `ProfileID` is unique based on the `CheckInDate`. In other words, records which have the same `ProfileID` and the same `CheckInDate` should appear only once (say only the record with the first `ResaID`). Records which have the same `ProfileID` but with different `CheckInDate` should appear in full (that is, if there are 2 records, output will include both records).

Based on the extract output given above, the desired output is as follows:

```
ResaID      CheckInDate    ProfileID

  100         2018-03-10      450
  101         2018-03-15      658
  103         2018-03-24      700
  115         2018-06-11      700
  127         2018-07-09      851
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: have you tried grouping by CheckinDate, ProfileId ?

Comment: what about resa1d 127? that's ignored in the expected output?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Sorry about that. I missed it. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT MIN(a.ResaID) AS FirstResaID,
       b.CheckInDate, 
       c.ProfileID  

FROM RSD a
LEFT JOIN GSS b on b.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN RS c on c.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN Profile d on d.ProfileID = c.ProfileID
GROUP BY c.ProfileID,b.CheckInDate;
```

I use `MIN()` to get the *first* `ResaID` - assuming this is an `IDENTITY` ID and the smaller value is the *first* one. If this is wrong, you'd need a `sorting` rule to define *the first*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT min(a.ResaID) ResaID, 
       b.CheckInDate, 
       c.ProfileID  

FROM RSD a
LEFT JOIN GSS b on b.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN RS c on c.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN Profile d on d.ProfileID = c.ProfileID
group by
       b.CheckInDate, 
       c.ProfileID
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use profile table.
Are you sure you need left join?

```
SELECT min(a.ResaID),
       b.CheckInDate, 
       c.ProfileID  
FROM RSD a
JOIN GSS b on b.ResaID = a.ResaID
JOIN RS c  on c.ResaID = a.ResaID 
group by b.CheckInDate, c.ProfileID
```

simplified version

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (id int primary key);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (id int primary key, fk int);

INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

INSERT INTO @T2
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2);

SELECT t1.id as [t1.id], t2.id as [t2.id], t2.fk as [t2.fk]
FROM @T1 T1
LEFT JOIN @T2 T2 
  ON t1.ID = t2.fk;

SELECT min(t1.ID) as minT1, t2.fk
FROM @T1 T1
LEFT JOIN @T2 T2 
  ON t1.ID = t2.fk
GROUP BY t2.fk;

SELECT min(t1.ID) as minT1, t2.fk
FROM @T1 T1
JOIN @T2 T2 
  ON t1.ID = t2.fk
GROUP BY t2.fk;
```

Comment: I wouldn't say a `LEFT JOIN` is voided by a `GROUP BY`. If you `GROUP BY` a column which resides in a table from a `LEFT JOIN` then the grouping will simply be on a value of *`NULL`*. Also, I believe you misspelt `MIN`. :)

Comment: @Larnu I did not say a group by.  I said the group by.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. Consider this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24ad9/1). The `LEFT JOIN` isn't voided, as `ID` simply has a value of *`NULL`* where there is no relationship. If it were "voided", then that row would not appear. (Unless you mean something entirely different by "voided", but that might therefore need explanation, as it's unclear).